# Highcharts categorized xAxis datetime - Change scaling from day to month

Tags: php, datetime, highcharts, scale

First of all this is my chart:

```
var options4 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: '#',
            type: '',
            width: width,
            height: height,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },


        title: {
            text: '#'

},

  subtitle: {
            text: '#'
},


xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickinterval: 30,
    categories: []
},


        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'%'
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Peakwert 30min',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: '',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],


        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: []


}

$.getJSON("voip/xTas/cpu.php", function(da1) {
    options4.xAxis.categories = da1[0]['data'];
    options4.series[0] = da1[1];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options4);
});
```

And this is my PHP:

```
$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Daytime';


$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'LEI3';
$series1['type'] = 'spline';


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['dtime'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['LEI3'];

}

$result = array();

array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
```

I got a lot of xAxis values that totally destroy the chart if tickinterval is set lower than 30. Actually I want to have monthly x values with zoom to the lower daytime values. I tried setting plotoptions with pointinterval and start, I tried to put pointstart and interval within the PHP, I really tried a lot but I can't make it work.

I got x values from 2013-11-12 00:00:00 to 2014-08-11 00:00:00 and I really want to have x values like January 2014, February 2014 and so on and if you zoom you will find the days.

Is this even possible?

Comment: `tickInterval` lower than 30 on a `datetime` is heavy for a chart that spans several months. Keep in mind that `tickInterval` in this case will be in milliseconds, so that is 0.03 seconds.

Comment: Also, ignoring your code, what is the ideal "look" of your x-axis? You only want to manage the tick labels, correct? What is it that isn't ideal just from letting Highcharts manage the tick labels and intervals?

Comment: Ideal would be Jan14, Feb14, Mar14 and so on and if you zoom in you'll see 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-31 for January for example.

And tickinterval for me is days not seconds or something so 30 days between two x Values so 2013-11-12 the first and the next one is 2013-12-07

Comment: `tickInterval` is in milliseconds for `datetime`. You've typed it with a small "i", which means it isn't in use.

Comment: I don't know why its a small "i" but its a capital one in my real script, sry for that but for me its not milliseconds.

Comment: Ok. I'd check [`dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) to set custom label texts depending on zoom.

Comment: How your JSON looks like ?